# Make me a hamburger!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

## The hamburger joint maHburger has hired you to write a program for them.

It is simple: make an ASCII hamburger, using the key. Sounds simple right? Well these customers are ***super*** picky, but one thing is for sure, they do love onions.

Write a program that accepts the customer's orders, and prints a hamburger with as many onions as possible.

### Key

```
O=Onions
P=Pickles
M=Mustard
K=Ketchup
#=Bread
.=Sesame Seed
&=Meat
_=Nothing
```

### Input

Through stdin, or closest alternative, your program will receive the customer's order.

Arguments: (number of patties) (Condiments preference) (number of pickles) (number of sesame seeds)

Condiments preference:

- M: more mustard (above 50% below 80%)
- K: more ketchup (above 50% below 80%)
- NM: nu mustard
- NK: no ketchup
- NMK: no condiments
- E: Ketchup and Mustard (between 40% and 60% each)

### Rules

- Pickles:

  - Size: 7-21
  - There must be a pickle that is at least 14 characters, if one or more pickles were ordered.
- Mustard:

  - Size: 2-7
  - No mustard may be touching Ketchup.
- Ketchup:

  - Size: 2-7
  - No ketchup may be touching Mustard.
- Onions:

  - If a onion is touching two M's, K's or P's It is considered an M, K, or P as well.
  - An onion may not be touching an M and an K at the same time.
  - An onion may not be at the edge of the hamburger.
  - Only up to 2 onions in and 5 character space.
- Sesame seeds are on the top bun only, and may not be touching each other.
- Nothing: only up to 10 per patty.
- Patties: Customers always order at least 2.

Example:

```
2 E 3 16
```

Means 2 patties, Normal condiments, 3 pickles, 16 sesame seeds

and could produce:

```
                  ###.##########
              ###.#############.####
          ##########.###################
       ###.######.######.######.######.####
     #######.#############.##################
   ###########################.################
  #################.#################.##########
 ###############.#############.##################
##################################################
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
_KKKKKK__MMMMMMMOPPPOPOP_O_PPPPPPOPPPPOPPPPPPPPPOP
##################################################
##################################################
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
KKKKKK_OMMMMMOMO_KOKPPOPPPPPO_MMMMMMMO_OKKKK__OO__
##################################################
##################################################
##################################################
```

### Code Golf

This is code golf, so the shortest code wins.
There are bonuses for the amount of onions your code produces, for the following test cases:

```
"2 E 3 16"      -5 bytes per onion
"8 M 25 17"     -1 byte per 5 onions
"2 NMK 5 13"    -8 bytes per onion
"2 NK 100 500" -20 bytes if your program prints "No maHburger for you!" for impossible hamburgers.
```

The bonuses may change.

### Format

```
# Language name, x bytes
How many onions your program produced, and the hamburgers the program created.
code
explanation (if needed)
```

### ASCII

Any whitespace that doesn't affect the ASCII art is fine.

```
                  ##############
              ######################
          ##############################
       ####################################
     ########################################
   ############################################
  ##############################################
 ################################################
##################################################
```

Is the top bun

```
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
```

Line of Condiments (50 char long)

```
##################################################
##################################################
```

for every patty

Standard Loopholes apply.

This is my first Code Golf Challenge! Yay!

This challenge was inspired by [this](http://archive.gdusa.com/egdusa/2015//0122e/_img/mcdonalds-loves-minimalism.jpg).

Comment: `No mustard may be touching Mustard.`...

Comment: Oops, forgot to change that to ketchup when I copied and pasted that.

Comment: @minxomat Fixed.

Comment: "There must be a pickle that is at least 14 characters, if one or more pickles were ordered." - however, I can't see such long sequence of `P` letters in the sample hamburger?

Comment: The onion counts as a P when it is surrounded by P's (onion rule 1)